# Display pandas dataframe as html table with scrollbars in django

Tags: python, html, css, django, pandas

I am working on a django project where I render a pandas dataframe in the context. I then iterate through this dataframe to display it in a table td td (html below).

I would like to get this as a fixed size with horizontal and vertical scrollbars instead when the dataframe is too large.

How can I do this?

```
<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                <tr>
                    {% for col in df.columns %}
                    <td>
                        <b>{{col}}</b>
                    </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% for index, row in df.iterrows %}
                    <tr>
                        {% for cell in row %}
                        <td>
                            {{cell}}
                        </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost there. Simply wrap the table in a div tag where you can specify the style; height, width, scrollbars etc. Also `iterrows` is an incredibly slow way to iterate over a dataframe. A much faster alternative is `itertuples` which includes the index as a first element which can be skipped (or included if so desired).

```html
<div style="height:300px; width:700px; overflow:auto;">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-light" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {% for col in df.columns %}
          <th style="text-align:center">{{col}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for row in df.itertuples %}
        <tr>
          {% for cell in row|slice:"1:" %}
            <td style="text-align:center">{{cell}}</td>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Then it renders a page that looks like which has the scrollbars if necessary.

[image: result]

Btw, the function in view.py used to pass the dataframe through context looks like:

```py
def mypage(request):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.default_rng(0).random(size=(100,10))).add_prefix('col')
    return render(request, 'mypage.html', {'df': df})
```

and I used `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">`  bootstrap in the base.html which the mypage.html page extends.